# Indexing HDFS files using elasticsearch

Tags: hadoop, indexing, elasticsearch, hbase

How to use Elasticsearch to index documents stored in HDFS? 
Does it help if the records are already stored as strings in JSON format?
I also have the data in HBase tables, if I can use Elasticsearch with HBase (whichever is more suitable).
Would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The elasticsearch guys have built some tools so that ES and Hadoop can play nice together. I have not used any of them but here is a link or two:

[Elasticsearch for Hadoop Doco](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/index.html)
[Elasticsearch for Hadoop Git Repo](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop)